# Save an empty array to mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a sub document that contains a key of 'comments' and a value of array. However, if my array is empty, the key value pair is not written to the database. I want it written as an empty array to the key 'comments'. How do I do this in express?

My schema looks like this:

```
  documentMaterials: [{
    docID: String,
    comments: [{
      name: String,
      createdDate: Date,
      comment: String,
    }],
    originalName: String,
    createdDate: Date,
    createdBy: String,
    description: String,
    docType: String,
    bucketName: String,
    chunkSize: Number,
    contentType: String,
    encoding: String,
    fieldname: String,
    filename: String,
    md5: String,
    metadata: Object,
    mimetype: String,
    size: Number,
    uploadDate: Date,
  }],

module.exports.updateById = function (id, object, callback) {
  Proposal.findByIdAndUpdate(id, object, {
    new: true
  }, callback);
}
```

Comment: updated to show my schema

Comment: Your code where you are inserting data?

Comment: updated to show save code

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set a **`default`** on your mongoose schema:

```
  comments: {
    type: [{
      name: String,
      createdDate: Date,
      comment: String,
    }],
    default: []
  }
```

More about arrays in mongoose and [setting defaults](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#arrays).